# Create a "clone" of an Angular2 component with ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a 3d "card flip" using angular 2. A parent 'card-flip' component contains a nested 'card-flip-front' and 'card-flip-back' component.

```
<card-flip card-flip-id="demo-1" class="grid_col-6">
  <card-flip-front class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      Card Front
    </div>
  </card-flip-front>
  <card-flip-back class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      Card Back
    </div>
  </card-flip-back>
</card-flip>
```

I would like to create a "clone" of the card-flip-front component with content projection and data-binding in tact. The "clone" would be used for animating and the "original" would remain in it's original position hidden. That way I have a reference of where the "clone" should animate to when it *returns* to the original position (even if the user scrolls or resizes the window).

The main challenge I'm facing is that I need the content within the `ng-content` tag to also be projected in the "clone". The problem being that the first `ng-content` tag will be used by Angular for content projection and additional, unlabeled `ng-content` tags will be empty (which I know is the expected behavior).

One might ask, "why not just create a dumb, static copy of the element in the DOM?". I would like to avoid this so that nested components and data bindings that inject data (thereby modifying the dimensions of the element) will continue to work.

Here's my work so far which creates an instance of the CardFlipFront component via ComponentFactory to serve as the "clone" and simply inserts the innerHTML of the "original" CardFlipFront.

```js
import { 
  Component,
  ComponentFactory,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  ContentChild,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef 
} from '@angular/core';
import { CardFlipFrontComponent } from './card-flip-front.component';
import { CardFlipBackComponent } from './card-flip-back.component';
import { CardFlipService } from './card-flip.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-flip',
  templateUrl: './card-flip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-flip.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [
    CardFlipFrontComponent
  ]
})
export class CardFlipComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('card-flip-id') public id: string;
  @ContentChild(CardFlipFrontComponent) private front: CardFlipFrontComponent;
  @ContentChild(CardFlipBackComponent) private back: CardFlipBackComponent;
  @ViewChild('frontCloneContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) private frontCloneContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  private frontComponentRef: ComponentFactory<CardFlipFrontComponent>;
  private frontClone: ComponentRef<CardFlipFrontComponent>;

  constructor(
    @Inject(CardFlipService) private _cardFlipService: CardFlipService,
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {
    this.frontComponentRef = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CardFlipFrontComponent);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._cardFlipService.register(this.id);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Create a card-flip-front component instance to serve as a "clone"
    this.frontClone = this.frontCloneContainer.createComponent(this.frontComponentRef);
    // Copy the innerHTML of the "original" into the "clone"
    this.frontClone.instance.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.front.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.frontClone.destroy();
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-content select="card-flip-front"></ng-content>
<ng-container #frontCloneContainer></ng-container>
<ng-content select="card-flip-back"></ng-content>
```

```js
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  HostBinding,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Renderer
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-flip-front',
  templateUrl: './card-flip-front.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-flip-front.component.css']
})
export class CardFlipFrontComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) { }

  public get el(): ElementRef {
    return this._el;
  }

  public get renderer(): Renderer {
    return this._renderer;
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

```html
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so after reading about some similar challenges and the [github issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7795), I tried the following.

```
<ng-template #frontTemplate>
  <ng-content select="card-flip-front"></ng-content>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngIf="isOpen == true" #front1>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="frontTemplate"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="isOpen == false" #front2>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="frontTemplate"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-content select="card-flip-back"></ng-content>
```

Basically, we can get around the single projection issue with `ng-content` by placing it within a template and using two `ng-container` tags with an `*ngIf` statement that will only show one instance of the template based on a class property `isOpen`.

This doesn't solve the entire issue though because only one container will be rendered at any given time. So, I can't get the current position of "original" to figure out where to animate the "clone" during the return animation described above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have an intermediary component `<card-flip-content>` inside `<card-flip>` template which is duplicated and which receives the `<ng-content>` of the `<card-flip>`.

Something like:

```
@Component(
   selector = 'card-flip',
   template = `
   <card-flip-content #theOne>
      <ng-content />
   </card-flip-content>
   <card-flip-content #theClone>
      <ng-content />
   </card-flip-content>
`)
```

Then bind data as needed to #theOne and #theClone and animate only #theClone.
This way  can have @Input and @Output thus leaving the actions of one component to be interpreted by the parent in order to act on the other component.

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the thought but I think I may be misunderstanding. In the example you provided you're using ng-content twice. Only the first ng-content tag will contain the projected content so the main problem still remains.

Comment: This limitation of ng-content is the intended behavior and is discussed at length here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7795